# How many connected components? (CSIR June'13)

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $X= \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2<5\}$ and K=$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 1\le x^2+y^2\le2 \quad\text{or}\quad 3\le x^2+y^2\le 4\}$
>   Then,
>
> 1.$X\setminus K$ has three connected components?
>
> 2.$X\setminus K$ has no relatively compact connected component in $X$.
>
> 3.$X\setminus K$ has two realtively compact connected components in $X$.
>
> 4.All components of $X\setminus K$ are relatively compact in $X$.

Please help me found what are correct options

> I think option 1,2 are correct since there will be three connected sets inside the larger disc of radius $5$ and they doesn't include their boundary therefore not compact , Am I correct?

Comment: Is "in $K$" in options 3 and 4 a misprint?

Comment: @Vladimir thanks for observing that , I've edited it now

Answer (score 1):

1 is correct (the three components are even path-connected).

As for the rest, you're certainly right that none of the components are compact (since compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces have to be closed). However, the question asks whether the components are [relatively compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relatively_compact_subspace) – that is, whether the *closures* of the components in the ambient space $X$ are compact. So, hint: What are the three closures (to emphasize, closure in the disk $X$ rather than the whole plane $\mathbb R^2$)? Which of these closures are compact?